# Open a new minimized window?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to open a new minimized browser window using javascript?

At the moment I have `onclick='window.open'`

Comment: What's your use case? I'm just curious why you would want to do such a thing. I'm not saying it's *impossible* that there's a non-evil reason for doing this, just that it's pretty *unlikely*...

Comment: absolutely just reciting what the customer has requested

Comment: ...so why does the customer want to open a popup that is then hidden from the user?  This smells like "we want to open an advertisement popup but initially hide it from the user so they don't know our site opened it"...

Comment: In my enterprise web app, I have a link to a ClickOnce thick client app. When the user clicks it the ClickOnce app should launch without a separate browser window and without redirecting from the launcher page. Sounds like browser security prohibits this kind of experience.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can try blurring the window and bringing the other window to the front, but you will not be able to minimize it.

```
var winpop = window.open(...);
winpop.blur();
window.focus();
```

Comment: Note many browsers these days have a security setting for this: **"Allow scripts to raise/lower windows"** and thus developers can not *expect* this to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

No. For security reasons... this is not possible... even the idea sounds spammy.